# React Native Push Notification onNotification callback is inconsistent

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push, react-native-push-notification

I've been using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) library for quite some time for local notifications. Now I need remote silent notifications. Basically I send a notification that gets delivered to onNotification callback and I send local notification to the notification center.

I expect onNotification callback to trigger every time I receive notification and I open an app by clicking on notification. The problem is, depending on where I call `PushNotification.configure({...})`, on Android it triggers onNotification when notification gets delivered OR when I click on it, but never both! My code:

```
// if here: calls onNotification when it's received
PushNotifications.configureNotifications();

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        // if here: calls onNotification when I click on it to open an app
        PushNotifications.configureNotifications();
        super(props);
    }

    render() { ... }
}
```

`PushNotifications.configureNotifications()` - it's just a simple wrapper over the library configure call. Yes, tried to keep it in both places - doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

I always send data payload in push notification.

Comment: Before I make an answer, as I am a bit new on this as well. I have read that in order to parse and receive foreground notifications you need to send show_in_foreground in your payload. I have to be honest I am not very familiar with that library you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says to not put the configuration in the React life-cycle. Otherwise Android won't have the right behavior (I had so mush pain with this point !).
Here you have a nice tutorial:
https://product.farewell.io/visible-react-native-push-notifications-that-work-on-both-ios-and-android-5e90badb4a0f
It's bad explained, but the approach is perfect. Use a class to initialize and call the methods. Initialize the class in the top component as he suggests. It works good. Complete the missing informations with this tutorial:
https://shift.infinite.red/react-native-node-js-and-push-notifications-e851b279a0cd
Have fun !

Comment: The thing is, Android part of this library works differently for different people, maybe depending on target SDK version or build tools version or something else. Anyways, I think your answer is a good starting point so I'll accept it. Thank you.